Pdf text clarity improver in python
this is a screenshot from a particular page in the pdf:

So I want to make these texts inside pdf's and make it higly contrast and clear not for just reading but for further processing the pdf.
Iam trying OCR, histogram equalization. which are not actually making the pdf images clear. So it will be helpful if you have the code or the apporoach to do the problem. Thank you.

That looks like you have a PDF with a low-resolution image (not text at all). It's hard to make it clearer without something pretty advanced like a superresolution neural net (see e.g. https://github.com/chaiNNer-org/spandrel for that).

tried ESRGAN but there was no improvement. https://www.kaggle.com/models/kaggle/esrgan-tf2/tensorFlow2
Any other suggestions ?

have used OCR methods but then there are many forms and table data so that unable to convert back to img or pdf

Actuall document document is a pdf and i have converted it to an image to do some enhancement techniques and give clarity to the texts. Is there any way to do text clarity enhancement. like i have to increase the clarity of the numbeers and letter inside the pdf
